# PHP: Array to variable function parameter values

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameters

I have a variable length array that I need to transpose into a list of parameters for a function.

I hope there is a neat way of doing this - but I cannot see how.

The code that I am writing will be calling a method in a class - but I will not know the name of the method, nor how many parameters it has.

I tried this - but it doesn't work:

```
$params = array(1 => "test", 2 => "test2", 3 => "test3");
ClassName::$func_name(implode($params, ","));
```

The above lumps all of the values into the first parameter of the function. Whereas it should be calling the function with 3 parameter values (test, test2, test3).

What I need is this:

```
ClassName::$func_name("test", "test2", "test3");
```

Any ideas how to do this neatly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
call_user_func_array('function_name', $parameters_array);
```

You can use this to call methods in a class too:

```
class A {
  public function doStuff($a, $b) {
    echo "[$a,$b]\n";
  }
}

$a = new A;
call_user_func_array(array($a, 'doStuff'), array(23, 34));
```

Comment: Cletus - Thanks!!

This worked a treat. I hope all the hair I pulled out will grow back :-)

Comment: Meanwhile using `Python` : `function_name(*parameters_array)`... I really got to love PHP.

Answer (score -2):

You could use `eval`:

```
  eval("$func_name(" . implode($params, ",") . ");");
```

Though you might need to do some lambda trickery to get your parameters quoted and/or escaped:

```
  $quoted_escaped_params = array_map(create_function('$a', 'return "\"". str_replace("\"",` "\\\"", $a) . "\""'), $params);
```

Comment: Yeah - Thanks Frank! I tried this but got bogged down with the quoting of the array values.

bit messy...