# php pass array to function as separate variables

Tags: php, object

i need to know how to pass an array to a function as separate variables, for instance,

```
function myfunction($var, $othervar) {
}

$myarray = array('key'=>'val', 'data'=>'pair');
```

here is where I am running into problems, the following doesn't seem to work:

```
$return = myfunction(extract($myarray));
```

it should, if I understand correctly, basically be the same as

```
$return = myfunction($key, $data);
```

where $key='val' and $data='pair'

can anyone please explain this to me.

Comment: You're looking for `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Array to variable function parameter values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793782/php-array-to-variable-function-parameter-values)

Comment: what about this:
it was:
$this->_obj[$key]->$function(extract($vars));
now it's:
return call_user_func_array(array(get_class($this->_obj[$key]), $function), $vars);
but this doesn't work because a non-static method 'can't' be called statically

Comment: given what you see above, how would you implement array_walk here?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question right then try this

```
$return = myfunction($myarray["key"],$myarray["data"]);
```

here we are simply passing the associative array as arguments.

Comment: that's useful but the problem there is that I don't know how many variables there are or what the keys are, i'll post the complete code in an answer below

Comment: should i just ignore the 'Strict Standards' error message and use call_user_func_array?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function get($key=null, $function='', array $vars=array()) {
        if ($key==null || !array_key_exists($key, $this->_obj)) {
            return null;
        }

var_dump($vars);

        if (!empty($function)) {
            return $this->_obj[$key]->$function(array_walk($vars));
//          return call_user_func_array(array(get_class($this->_obj[$key]), $function), $vars);
//          return $this->_obj[$key]->$function(extract($vars));
        }
        return $this->_obj[$key];
    }
```

Comment: now with call_user_func_array I'm getting this:  Using $this when not in object context in C:\aDomain\profordable\lib\Class_Database.php on line 42 because apparently using call_user_function_array(array('class', 'function'), $vars) with an array as the function name, calls the method statically

Comment: I was passing the class in call_user_func_array as a string instead of as an object, what i have now is below, and it seems to work, although more input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function get($key=null, $function='', array $vars=array()) {
        if ($key==null || !array_key_exists($key, $this->_obj)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!empty($function)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($this->_obj[$key], $function), $vars);
        }
        return $this->_obj[$key];
    }

$registry = Registry_Object::Singleton();
//...later on
$registry = $GLOBALS['registry'];
$registry->set('Content', new Content($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$id = $registry->get('Content', 'GetIdFunc');
$registry->set('DB', 'Database');
$query = $registry->get('DB', 'Read', array("SELECT TITLE, CONTENT FROM APP_CONTENT WHERE ID=$id"));
print '<h1>'.$query[0]['TITLE'].'</h1>';
print Template_Helper::TPL_Paragraphs($query[0]['CONTENT']);
```

thanks all